# what is wrong with the linq command?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to find the type of the `Enumerable`. my code is like this:

```
Type[] intLikeTypes = new[] { typeof(int), typeof(decimal), typeof(long), typeof(float) };
List<int> columnValue = new List<int>();
columnValue.Add(1);
columnValue.Add(2);

var listType = columnValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
Type listGenericType = columnValue.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();
if (listGenericType == typeof(List<>))
{
    bool isInstanceOfTypeInt = (listType == typeof(int));
    if (intLikeTypes.Any(x => x.IsInstanceOfType(listType)))

        resColumnValue=preProcessValue(columnVal, false, false);

    else if (listType is string)

        resColumnValue=preProcessValue(columnVal, true, false);

}
```

when I use `bool isInstanceOfTypeInt = (listType == typeof(int))`, the `isInstanceOfTypeInt` is `true`. However,  the `if(intLikeTypes.Any(x => x.IsInstanceOfType(listType))` condition is `false`. why `x.IsInstanceOfType(listType)` cannot find the instance properly?

by the way, the `linq` command is working for the `columnValue` other than `list<int>` type. For example, it is working for `int` type.

Comment: If you're trying to compare the types just do `intLikeTypes.Any(x => x == listType)` because x is already a `Type`.

Comment: thanks @thepirat000 ! see my comment in the suggested answer!

Comment: a better name for `intLikeTypes` would be `numericTypes` ;)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary yes you are right!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the condition

```
if (intLikeTypes.Any(x => x.IsInstanceOfType(listType)))
```

with

```
if (intLikeType.Any(x => x == listType))
```

By the way, the condition

```
if (listGenericType == typeof(List<>))
```

is always evaluated to true, and I think there is no cause to evaluate this to false.

**UPDATE**

the method `IsInstanceOfType` determine if the "Type" of the variable is of a specific type, it does NOT Determine if the type is the same to another type (the case that your code is doing)

for example, consider the following example

```
int s = 5;
bool test = typeof(int).IsInstanceOfType(s);
```

the value of the 'test' variable will be true because the type of s variable is int

but the following code will evaluate to false

```
Type intType = typeof(int);
bool test = typeof(int).IsInstanceOfType(intType);
```

here the 'test' variable will have the value of 'false' because the variable 'intType' which of type "Type" is not an int

here is part of the documentation of this method

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Boolean
>
> true if the current Type is in the inheritance hierarchy of the object represented by o, or if the current Type is an interface that implements. false if neither of these conditions is the case, if o is null, or if the current Type is an open generic type (that is, ContainsGenericParameters returns true).

see the documentation of this method for more information.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinstanceoftype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks @Hakam Fostok! but my question is why `IsInstanceOfType` is not working in this case because it is okay for other types! I used `if (listGenericType == typeof(List<>))` because I have other types! it is just an example!

Comment: do you mean the condition will be true for this statement  bool isInstanceOfTypeInt = (listType == typeof(long)); if you mean that you are not right, also this will not working at all

Comment: yes! you are right! it only works for type int but why it is not working for others!?

Comment: Also resharper says `typeof(int).IsInstanceOfType(listType)` is equivalent to `listType is int`. and you know `Type` is not `int` ;)